# Fastest way to check if values in list are in dataframe using R

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the fastest way to check if values in a list are in a dataframe?

Here is what I have tried (on a much larger dataset with a much larger list)

```
#list
list_vals <- list("a", "b", "c", "d")

#dataframe
df <- data.frame(col1 <- c("1", "a", "c"),
                 col2 <- c("24a" , "d", "b"))

#function to check presence 
pmt_present <- function(x) {
  present <- any(df==x)
  return(present)
}

#run check for vals in df
present_list <- lapply(list_vals, pmt_present)

#create df of results
present_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(list_vals, present_list))
```

My code was running all night and when I stopped it it threw this error

`Error in base::try(sample_long_mutate, silent = TRUE) : object 'sample_long_mutate' not found`

But it works perfectly in the small example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%in%` along with `unlist`

```
> unlist(list_vals) %in% unlist(df)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Wow so much faster. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Or may also do

```
list_vals %in% t(df)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```